# How do I make my translation less stilted or flow similar to the original Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, nuances, word-requests

I'm translating the following line of dialogue spoken by Character A to Character B.

「怖がらなくてもいいわ。もう襲ったりしないから」

The translations I made are the following:

> "There’s no need to be afraid. Because I will no longer be attacking you anymore.”
>
> "There’s no need to be afraid. Because I will be no longer attacking you anymore.”

This became a issue on the [English stack exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494308/what-are-the-naunces-of-the-placement-of-be-in-the-following-two-sentences), when I tried asking for some help with the placement of the word 'be', as shown in the above link.

A commenter over there suggested 
"Because I will not be attacking you anymore." which sounds stilted for the character's dialogue.

I need some possible English translations that will work for the translation of しない (to do nai form I.E. "will no longer/will not be" in the above translations), that are not stilted or flow similar to Japanese.

My reason for requesting a translation that will flow similar to Japanese is that this story is similar to Star Wars as far as languages go. Its similar in that the in-story language being spoken by the characters is currently Japanese, but as a translator, I need to convey this using the vernacular of the English language.

TDLR: What is a good English replacement for "will no longer/will not be" that is natural in English and flows similar to Japanese?

Comment: won't attack you anymore????

Comment: Is this a question of Japanese or English?

Comment: It really does seem to me like you’re asking about English here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread may well be closed, as the question does indeed seem to be more about the English than the Japanese.  That said, here's my take:

When translating, it's often more important to focus on the meaning and intent, and to convey that in a natural fashion.  For example, Japanese often structures things as `ABC。XYZ から` → `Thing ABC. Reason XYZ.`  English often relates similar content with either the reverse order, or by putting the two sentences together.  As examples: *"I'm done attacking you, so you don't need to be afraid anymore."*  Or, *"No need to be afraid, I'm done attacking you."*  Etc.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the answer I was going to post, +1. Sometimes when I'm really struggling to translate something into natural English, I'll produce an (awkward) literal translation, and then focus on rewriting that English into better English.

Comment: @Mindful: That's a good approach, and one that native-English writing teachers sometimes advocate -- get the words on paper first to get the meaning down, and then work on polishing it into better wording and smoother fluency.